# Anatomical Angle Made by the Fingers of an Extended Palm

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, anatomy, literature, morphometry

Does the angle made by the fingers (excluding the thumb) of an extended palm (as shown in the figure below) have a name (such as the [Lovibond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nail_clubbing) or [Cobb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobb_angle) angle, for instance) ?

[image]

I have already checked [*Modeling the Constraints of Human Hand Motion*](http://www.ifp.illinois.edu/~yingwu/papers/Humo00.pdf), published by the [*Beckman Institute for Advanced Science and Technology*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beckman_Institute_for_Advanced_Science_and_Technology) at the [*University of Illinois at Urbana-Champaign*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_Illinois_at_Urbana-Champaign), but it failed to provide any answers. (Perhaps there aren't any ?) Any input would be *deeply* appreciated.

Comment: I searched through a few documents such as [Biesecker et al. (2009)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3224990/) but could not find anything so far. I would guess there aren't any terms for that. Did you make the figure or did you find it somewhere? Where is it from? Knowing your interest for this term might eventually be helpful. [english.se] could also be a good place to ask this question.

Comment: @Remi.b: The question originated in my own mind, as an unintended byproduct of various measurements performed on my own body, in an attempt to understand the ancient and medieval measuring systems, such as those still employed by the Anglo-Saxon world today.